# javafx UNKNOWN duration on Media object

Tags: java, audio, javafx, media

I am a newbie to both Java and JavaFX, I've spent the last couple years developing on Python with QT, and I am now developing in Java and JavaFX.

I am developing a program that plays music files for the users set time and then stops. Be that as such, I am in need of getting the duration from the Media Object in order to tell the audio when to stop (based on the users time input), however, the getDuration() method on a media object always returns UNKNOWN.

I am using JDK8u25 (the latest stable release) on both Windows 8.1 and openSuSE 13.2 (both have the same issue):

```
File filestring = new File("my/file/dir/file.mp3")
Media file = new Media(filestring.toURI().toString());
file.getDuration(); // Returns UNKNOWN on both wav and mp3 files
file.getDuration().toMinutes()) // Also tested with toHours() toSeconds(), toMilli()...
// Above returns NaN because the file's duration is unknown
```

Just as a test, I put my whole mp3 music collection (1,000+ songs with both CBR and VBR) and had java iterate through each file and all of them said duration was UNKNOWN. I also tried wav files from multiple different sources (just to make sure it wasn't the mp3 format) to see if that changed and...nothing; nothing but UNKNOWN for duration. I also checked to make sure the tags are inplace which every other program says the length or duration in the files properties for these files are good.

What's weird is that the file plays perfectly when I pass the Media object into a MediaPlayer. Though I could use an external library for getting the length, but seeing as the whole program uses java and javafx libraries, this would be much easier and more streamlined.

### Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you read the javadoc for `Media` class, it says you should wait for the media player to be ready:

> The media information is obtained asynchronously and so not necessarily available immediately after instantiation of the class. All information should however be available if the instance has been associated with a MediaPlayer and that player has transitioned to Status.READY status

So you just need to create an instance of `MediaPlayer` and listen for the `Status.READY`:

```
    File filestring = new File("my/file/dir/file.mp3");
    Media file = new Media(filestring.toURI().toString());  

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(file);

    mediaPlayer.setOnReady(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            System.out.println("Duration: "+file.getDuration().toSeconds());

            // display media's metadata
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : file.getMetadata().entrySet()){
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
            }

            // play if you want
            mediaPlayer.play();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Answered my question. It works. Thank you! To clarify so I understand this here...The Media file is declared Status.READY (and the information able to be obtained) when it is passed into MediaPlayer? Or when it the setonReady method is called?

Comment: also is there a method I can call to set that media file to status.READY without waiting for java to set it? It works (I get the duration and metadata) when I put statements in the run() method override (as you mentioned above), but putting a call to the duration even the line after it goes back to UNKNOWN

Comment: The runnable is not called immediatly. It is called when the media is ready. This can take milliseconds up to minutes. You need to wait for ne media to be ready to get the information!

Comment: As @Tobi says, you have to wait for the ready status. If you are interested in knowing the duration of a list of files, you could implement one task to go through all the files. For each file, it should create a mediaplayer, wait for the ready status and then get the duration and move to the next one.

Comment: all good. Thanks guys. I was trying to use the duration right after I created the media object so I refactored my program a bit to give java time to get the Media ready and I am all good

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Media needs some time to get fully initialized. Add a Thread sleep beforebthe getDuration line and try again!

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned and accepted answer is correct, so you cannot access or get total duration before `mediaplayer` gets ready, and you should use `mediaPlayer.setOnReady()...`.

But sometimes you need to know about the total duration of a mp3 file in a faster manner. In such cases you can use third parties libraries like [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/). To use it you can import the following dependencies to your `pom.xml` file:

```
<!-- Apache Tika: detects and extracts metadata and text from a variety of files -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>


<!--Apache Tika AudioVideo Parser Module-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-parser-audiovideo-module</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The you can find the duration of your media files as follows:

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(browsedFile.getFilePath());
ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
Parser parser = new Mp3Parser();
ParseContext parseCtx = new ParseContext();
parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseCtx);
input.close();
Long duration = Long.parseLong(metadata.get("xmpDM:duration").split("\\.")[0]);
```

And of-course you can format it in more human-readable format:

```
String formattedDuration = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", duration / 3600, (duration % 3600) / 60, (duration % 60));
```