# Duration in seconds always returns 0

Tags: java, jframe, media, jfxpanel

My main class contains these lines of code. (There is also a JButton that adds files to the playlist)

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;


public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    MusicPlayerGUI m = new MusicPlayerGUI();
    m.setSize(100,100);
    m.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    m.setVisible(true);
 }
}

class MusicPlayerGUI extends JFrame{
static DefaultListModel<String>  model  =  new  DefaultListModel<>();
int currentTrack = 0;
int count=0;
int status = 0;
List<Media> playlist  = new ArrayList<>();
JFXPanel jfx = new JFXPanel();
MediaPlayer mp; 
javax.swing.JButton btnAdd = new javax.swing.JButton("add");

public MusicPlayerGUI() {
    add(btnAdd);
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnAddActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

} 
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    PlaylistManager pm = new PlaylistManager();
    JFileChooser loader = new JFileChooser();
    loader.showOpenDialog(this);
    pm.addSongToPlaylist(loader.getSelectedFile());
}

}
```

This is another class, PlaylistManager, that manages my playlist - operations like add, remove files from playlist happen here.

```
public class PlaylistManager extends MusicPlayerGUI{

  public PlaylistManager(){};

  public void addSongToPlaylist(File file){

    Media songToBeAdded = new Media(file.toURI().toString());
    playlist.add(songToBeAdded); //effectively adds a song to the playlist
    MusicPlayerGUI.model.addElement(file.getName());  //adds to the visual model of the playlist (as am UI element)
    System.out.println("Added song: " + file.getName()+" with duration of " +(int)(songToBeAdded.getDuration()).toSeconds());
    count++; //increments count of songs in playlist each time one is added
}
```

The problem is that, every time I add a song to the playlist, the duration is always read as 0.
The console prints:

> Added song: name_of_the_song.mp3 with duration of 0

Why does it happen like that? What's the reason why it can't read duration properly (javafx.util.duration) ? And how can I fix that ?

Comment: what is the Media class ?? show us the code

Comment: What is `currentTrack`? What is its value? Please create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: @Ravi - Media class https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html  javafx.scene,media

Comment: Does it even compile ???? I don't see anywhere `currentTrack ` declared

Comment: @some-programmer-dude My bad, i forgot to add the variables. Updated. If i forgot something again, let me know

Comment: @Dan You get any clue/help from my post, then you need to accept/upvote the post.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27208590/5457643)  answer. Basically the information is not necessarily available immediately after creating the `Media` object.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that, everytime i add a song to the playlist, the
>   duration is **always read as 0**.

As per you code implementation (since, I'm not sure what file and what is the duration it has)

You initialized current track and count

```
int currentTrack = 0;
int count=0;
```

But, whenever you are adding track, you are just incrementing `count` not `currentTrack`

```
System.out.println("Added song: " + file.getName()+" with duration of " +(int)(playlist.get(currentTrack).getDuration()).toSeconds());
```

I'm not sure, why are incrementing `count` and not `currentTrack`, although you are using `currentTrack` to get the duration of current track. So, after each iteration of adding file your will growing, but you are still print **first** track duration as `currentTrack` is still `0`.

Now, I'm assuming the duration of first track is 0, if not, then you should check verify your code and added file for the same.